# Assign method to private delegate without breaking the current assignment

Tags: c#, delegates, system.reflection, propertyinfo, methodinfo

I'd like to use private delegate from some class, but without breaking the current assignment. 
Can I somehow ensure that my changes (done by reflection) do not disconnect WriteToDebug?

**Delegate is private and "Inform" is private**

```
public class ExternalClass
{
    private delegate void InformDelegate(string info);//PRIVATE!
    private InformDelegate Inform { get; set; }//PRIVATE!

    public ExternalClass()
    {
        Inform = WriteToDebug;//Default method
    }

    public void Foo(string bar)
    {
        Inform?.Invoke(bar);
    }

    private void WriteToDebug(string info)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Info: {info}");
    }
}
```

**Adding my method to the delegate and some test (Debug.WriteLine + MessageBox.Show are required)**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void Test(string message)
    {
        ExternalClass externalClass = new ExternalClass();
        externalClass.Foo(message);

        //Assign MyMethod to SomeClass.Inform            
        MethodInfo mi = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(MyMethod), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        PropertyInfo pi = externalClass.GetType().GetProperty("Inform", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(pi.PropertyType, this, mi);
        Type type = externalClass.GetType().GetNestedType("Inform", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        pi.SetValue(externalClass, del);

        //Try Foo again
        externalClass.Foo(message);//TODO: Ensure that the call "Inform? .Invoke (bar);" triggered both methods: WriteToDebug and MyMethod.
    }

    private void MyMethod(string msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}
```

**Verification**

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.Test("Hello Word!");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

*I will be grateful for your help*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **combine** your delegate with the existing one (here: pointing to `WriteToDebug`) via [Delegate.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Retrieve this already existing one via:

```
Delegate original = pi.GetValue(externalClass) as Delegate;
```

and combine your new one via:

```
Delegate combined = Delegate.Combine(original, del);
```

Note that the order of the passed in delegates represents the order of execution.

Your full code from above will look like below.

```
ExternalClass externalClass = new ExternalClass();

MethodInfo mi = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(MyMethod), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
PropertyInfo pi = externalClass.GetType().GetProperty("Inform", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(pi.PropertyType, this, mi);

Delegate original = pi.GetValue(externalClass) as Delegate;
Delegate combined = Delegate.Combine(original, del);

pi.SetValue(externalClass, combined);

externalClass.Foo(message);
```

Comment: Yes, excellent! It works even if Inform == null. Thank you very much @pfx

Comment: Do you know how to extend it so that you can pass an additional parameter to the MyMethod method (a parameter that is not present in the original delegate, but is known during the execution of Delegate.Combine). So Inform will still call WriteToDebug (string info), but also MyMethod (string msg, string EXTRA_PARAMETER). EXTRA_PARAMETER will be served somewhere in the code that @pfx proposed. But where and how to do it?

Comment: EXTRA_PARAMETER can be transferred when the appropriate overload is used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Delegate_CreateDelegate_System_Type_System_Object_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_